# Passing a date to a context variable

Tags: talend

I am trying to pass a date from a table to context variable. After that I want to use this variable in an sql query to get data later than that date.

I used to tJavarow and my variable seems to have null value.

First table is in Postgresql and the second table is in Mysql.

I have setup date as  "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" in edit schema.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: passing values to context is not that tricky..but can be tricky with dates..so can you show your code or screenshot to see the issue...what is the type of context variable? is it date or string? also when you read date from mysql table, what is the data type of date column in schema in the input component

Comment: I have added screenshots. Context variable is date type. I have set it up as "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

Comment: ok.thanks, still missing schema details. can you click on schema button in sales_flat_order and do same for configuration_table and tJavaRow_1 and please share them as that is important to check what is the datatype you are using for all these schema columns around date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Date type context variable in SQL query you need to transform it to String with correct pattern. Try do like this:

```
`created_at` > '" + TalendDate.formatDate("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", context.created_at) + "' "
```